# What am I doing wrong with PSTricks 3D?

Tags: pstricks, pst-3dplot

I'm starting doing graphs with PSTricks in 3D, but I can't reach a first good result.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
% -------- Paquetes de pst-all \usepackage{pst-all}   paquete pstricks para        
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-3d}
\usepackage{pst-eps}
\usepackage[tiling]{pst-fill}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{multido}
% ---- Fin Paquetes de pst-all

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1.5, Alpha=45, Beta=30}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-1.5)(3,4)
\pstThreeDCoor[xMin=-4,xMax=4,yMin=-4,
yMax=4,zMax=3, arrows=<->]
\psplotThreeD[plotstyle=line,linecolor=blue,
yPlotpoints=40,xPlotpoints=30, linewidth=0.5pt,
hiddenLine=true](-2,2)(-2,2)
{
x 100 mul cos y 100 mul sin sub
}
\rput[tl](-2,3.5){$f(x,y)=\cos (100x) - \sin (100y) $ }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Why are you loading all those packages? (That is not nessecasy at all.) (2) You need to load the `pst-3dplot` package.

Comment: Not one of the examples in this thread generate any visible results on my MikTeX distribution using WinShell. I can create a DVI file but it crashes YAP when I try to look at it and pdflatex only creates lots of "Error: Undefined control sequence.".

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "[Ask Question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need the following:

```
% latex filname.tex
% dvips filname.dvi
% ps2pdf filname.ps

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.2,-2.73)(3.18,3.65)
\pstThreeDCoor[
  xMin = -4,
  xMax = 4,
  yMin = -4,
  yMax = 4,
  zMax = 3,
  arrows = <->
]
\psplotThreeD[
  plotstyle = line,
  linecolor = blue,
  yPlotpoints = 40,
  xPlotpoints = 30,
  linewidth = 0.5pt,
  hiddenLine = true
](-2,2)(-2,2)
{x 100 mul cos y 100 mul sin sub}
\rput(0,3.5){$f(x,y) = \cos(100x) - \sin(100y)$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Do you know that  you have some unnecessary `%` characters?

Comment: @mozartstraße Yes, but Herbert told me to be careful when putting each option on a line of its own (and no one knows PSTricks better than him), so I'm being overly cautious.

Comment: Commas are enough to delimit the key-value items. See http://pastebin.com/mmZmPrVE

Comment: Also please see this comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9890076#9890076

Answer (score 11):

You need the [`pst-3dplot`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pst-3dplot) package. You don't need all the others - here's a complete MWE

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: on}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1.5, Alpha=45, Beta=30}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-1.5)(3,4)
    \pstThreeDCoor[xMin=-4,xMax=4,yMin=-4,
    yMax=4,zMax=3, arrows=<->]
    \psplotThreeD[plotstyle=line,linecolor=blue,
        yPlotpoints=40,xPlotpoints=30, linewidth=0.5pt,
    hiddenLine=true](-2,2)(-2,2)
    {
        x 100 mul cos y 100 mul sin sub
    }
    \rput[tl](-2,3.5){$f(x,y)=\cos (100x) - \sin (100y) $ }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with package `pst-solides3d`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5,viewpoint=50 40 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=25,lightsrc=viewpoint,
  stepX=2,stepY=2,stepZ=2}
\begin{pspicture}(-9,-8)(8,6)
\psSurface[ngrid=.5 .5,linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,axesboxed,
   algebraic,hue=0 1](-10,-10)(10,10){ cos(100*x)-sin(100*y) }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]